# ucommerce throwing 404 - Umbraco 7.5.3

Tags: umbraco-ucommerce

We are using Umbraco ver 7.5.3 and we have ucommerce installed which was working fine from years. Just last week it started throwing errors on ucommerce picker for products and also while uploading media to ucommerce products. See attached.

This issue is only happening on prod and not on local or staging environments.

Any help appreciated

[image]